# in Javascript how do i target an array entry with "push" function?

Tags: javascript

i've been struggling with this, would appreciate help.

i'm looking to update the value of "v.low" to like 6000 (manually) outside of the loop at the last index position in the array (last index = latest timestamp, so its current time). 
But i can't target the entry properly in the array with JS.

here is an example - but the below is sitting in a loop where "v" is associated to the row in array

```
  chartList[container]['option'].series[0].data.push([
    v.open,
    v.close,
    v.low,    ----< want to update its value here to 6000
    v.high
  ]);
```

//i'm trying it this way, but its obviously wrong, want to update low @ last index position

chartList[container]['option'].series[0].data[ *arraylength-1* ].low=6000;
----> also tried this:
 chartList[container]['option'].series[0].data[ *arraylength-1* ].push('low',6000);

//i essentially want to update the value of "low" at the last index in array "chartList[container]['option'].series[0].data"

Here is the code

---

```
// List all data candle
  $.each(dataParsed.candles, function(k, v){ vListChart.push(v.close);   });



  if(jQuery.inArray(dataParsed.candles[dataParsed.candles.length - 1].date, chartList[container]['option'].xAxis[0].data) === -1){

  //  showAlert('we have new data');        

    chartList[container]['option'].series[0].data = chartList[container]['option'].series[0].data.slice(0, -4);
    chartList[container]['option'].series[1].data = chartList[container]['option'].series[1].data.slice(0, -4);
    chartList[container]['option'].xAxis[0].data = chartList[container]['option'].xAxis[0].data.slice(0, -4);

    chartList[container]['data_candles'] = chartList[container]['data_candles'].slice(0, -4);
    chartList[container]['data_candles'] = $.merge(chartList[container]['data_candles'], dataParsed.candles);

    chartList[container]['data'] = chartList[container]['data'].slice(0, -4);
    chartList[container]['data'] = $.merge(chartList[container]['data'], vListChart);

    $.each(dataParsed.candles, function(k, v){
      chartList[container]['option'].xAxis[0].data.push(v.date);
      chartList[container]['option'].series[0].data.push([
        v.open,
        v.close,
        v.low,
        v.high
      ]);

      if(k == dataParsed.candles.length - 1){
        chartList[container]['option'].series[1].data.push(v.open);
      } else {
        chartList[container]['option'].series[1].data.push(v.close);
      }

    });
```

/// this is the candle formation

```
echo json_encode([
  'error' => 0,
  'candles' => $listCandles,
  'current_price' => $Coin->_getPrice(),
  'notification_list' => $listNotification,
  'order_list' => $listOrder,
  'internal_order' => $internalOrderList,
  'currency' => $CryptoApi->_getCurrency()
]);
```

Comment: As the documentation very clearly states, push is used to append a new element to the end of an array and can not be used to update an a specific value inside the array. Try ```chartList[container]['option'].series[0].data[lastIndex].low = 6000```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chartList[container]['option'].series[0].data[ arraylength-1 ][2]=6000
```

note that this will not affect the object referenced by v.

Comment: i love u man!!! this worked finally, i spent 3 hrs here, thank youthank youthank youthank you